# How to run two fragments properly next to each other (including camera)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, zxing

I am currently creating an application to scan products. I am using [this library](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) for scanning the product codes. I just started to develop for tablets and I want to use two fragments next to each other (at the right side the camera, left side the information), but I'm running into a problem.

Initially I start with the camera opened fullscreen. Whenever a product code is scanned, I want to open a second fragment showing the information about this product. This is working fine, but when I want to scan a next product code, the result handler of the camera fragment is never called.

My first thought of this problem is that the focus is getting lost when the second fragment opens, but I'm not sure if this is right.

This is my source code:

**Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(...);
    resultHandler = new SimpleResultHandler();
    initCameraFragment(CodeScannerFragment.newInstance(resultHandler);
}

private void initCameraFragment(CodeScannerFragment scannerFragment) {
    mScannerFragment = scannerFragment;

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    manager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.packing_scanner_frame, scannerFragment)
            .commit();
}

// Called when the code information is retrieved
public void showProductInformation(ProductInformation info) {
    FrameLayout packingFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.packing_detail_frame);
    if (packingFrame != null) {
        packingFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mPackingFragment = ProductInformationFragment.newInstance(info);
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.packing_detail_frame, (PackingDetailsFragment) mPackingFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

**Scanner fragment**

```
public static CodeScannerFragment newInstance(ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler resultHandler) {
    return new CodeScannerFragment().setResultHandler(resultHandler);
}

private CodeScannerFragment setResultHandler(ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler resultHandler) {
    mResultHandler = resultHandler;

    return this;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    scannerView.setResultHandler(resultHandler);
    scannerView.startCamera();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    scannerView.stopCamera();
}
```

**Result handler**

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    String data = result.getText();
    ProductInformation info = ...;
    activity.showProductInformation(info);
}
```

***NOTE: I changed some code on stackoverlow, to protect the real code (so typo's are possible).***

Anyone who could help me with this problem?

Comment: viewpager is best solution for this.

Comment: But I want to constantly show them both (just like master/detail view), this ain't possible with a viewpager right?

Comment: Post your activity xml file also.